# Format first line of a multiline TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, format, render

I have multiline TextView, I need to format only single line of it. Since font size and style is dynamic I need it to format "first line" automatically.

**This TextView is displaying a string without linefeed, it is wrapped automatically, I need to format first wrapped line.**

Please check attached image:

[image]

Comment: html texts ddnt work?

Comment: @MohammedAtif, no since text is dynamic and I don't which words are in first line so I can style them in HTML

Comment: Dynamic text in the sense? Is it from some random source or the text is generated by someone of your own team?

Comment: so how you define first line with dynamic text, it's the solution.

Comment: @MohammedAtif It's not random, it's title of a card, I want to make first line (what ever it is) bolder

Comment: line breaking is done dynamically, depending on font size!

Comment: @AVEbrahimi you should have line breaking in first line with your dynamic text, it's best solution.

Comment: While @Hitesh's solution make full sense, I am still unable to figure out what is stopping you to format first line of your content as bold. Can you even provide the exact string that you are receiving.

Comment: @MohammedAtif There is no LINE BREAK in text, it is braked by system, it's a visual text wrap, no \n in actual text.

Comment: Then, even if you manage to figure out first line by some means the moment you bold it, part of it will go to next line because of size expansion.

Comment: Best solution that comes to my mind currently is give character limit for first line, (tiral and error basis) words and characters, consider them and bold them, push everything else to next line.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution that uses StaticLayout.

```
private TextView tvTitle; //bold title with maxLines = 1
private TextView tvText; //the rest of the text

//initialize views, etc...

private void showText(@Nonnull String text) {
    tvTitle.setText(text);

    tvTitle.post(() -> {
        String ellipsizedText = getEllipsizedText(text, tvTitle);
        tvText.setText(ellipsizedText);
    });
}

private static String getEllipsizedText(String text, TextView textView) {
    StaticLayout staticLayout = getStaticLayout(text,
            textView.getPaint(),
            textView.getWidth(),
            1,
            null);
    return text.substring(staticLayout.getLineEnd(0));
}

private static StaticLayout getStaticLayout(CharSequence text,
                                            TextPaint paint,
                                            int width,
                                            int maxLines,
                                            TextUtils.TruncateAt ellipsize) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(text, 0, text.length(), paint, width)
                .setTextDirection(TextDirectionHeuristics.FIRSTSTRONG_LTR)
                .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                .setLineSpacing(0f, 1f)
                .setIncludePad(false)
                .setEllipsize(ellipsize)
                .setEllipsizedWidth(width)
                .setMaxLines(maxLines)
                .build();
    } else {
        return new StaticLayout(text,
                paint,
                width,
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                1f,
                0f,
                false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from @HiteshGehlot's answer:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>This is a normal</b><br>second line<br>third line"));
```

but as your system is dynamic, this is not a good way to do it. This code generates the appropriate HTML:

```
String lines[] = string.split("\\n");
String fl = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "<b>%s</b><br>", lines[0]);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(fl);
for(int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++){
    sb.append(lines[i] + "<br>");
}
String finalProduct = sb.toString();
```

then:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(finalProduct));
```

This should dynamically create the HTML tags for the first line

---

**EXPLANATION**

This is an improvement from a previous answer. Using HTML, the first line is formatted as bold.

Using regex, we split all the lines by newline(\n). The first String in the array is the first line, while the rest aren't important to format. So first we append the first line, and add the rest after that. The for-loop starts at 1 since 0 is the first line.

### NOTE

If you do break the text dynamically, you pass that String into the method above. The method I have presented here uses those linebreaks to figure out which line is where, to be able to set the first line to be bold

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>This is a normal</b><br>second line<br>third line"));
```

Comment: if your text is dynamic just pass String object which contain first line, second line so on..

Comment: line breaking is done dynamically, depending on font size!

Answer (score -1):

Just use another TextView.
TextView1, TextView2, TextView3.
And set TextView1 to bold.

Comment: line breaking is done dynamically, depending on font size!